# Can't redirect to same page when using GET in a form

Tags: php, html

I am fairly new to using PHP so bear with me if this is a stupid question

I have a form that comprises a number of radio buttons, the action is set to redirect to the same page and the method is GET.

A click on a radio button gets data from the database. The data is used to redisplay the same page with changed content.

The page URL has PHP arguments in it like the example below

localhost/basesite/mypage.php?itemID=8&name=city&number=9

When I access the page and click on a radio button I get a page with “no arg” because the URL reads

localhost/basesite/mypage.php?number=6

Two of the arguments are missing and that the last one is incorrect.

With no change whatsoever to the code except using ”post’ instead of “get” the whole thing works flawlessly.

I have used

form action= "" method=“get”

form action= “#” method=“get”

and many other actions using $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI”], $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] etc and combinations thereof.

Those that worked with POST did not work with GET.

I do not need to use POST as data is not written only retrieved from the database so I have no worry about data being written more than once.

If I have to I will use POST but if the user refreshes or uses the back button then the usual warnings will be issued by the browser.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

you should you use $.get which is a jquery method.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should share your full source code for better understanding your problem. And also you have to use post method to submit a radio button values to get some value from your database. Form data can be submitted using these two methods (get and post). Both are used for the same purpose, but stands apart under some specifications. As in GET method key values are passed in the Url while in POST, the information transfers in a hidden manner.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks. It was a badly formed URL due to me not fully understanding how to set a hidden element.